# How to make a reference slide in beamer? mine only showed a '?'

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

> My code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Reference}
\cite{bilson1978rational}.
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{abc.bib} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> My abc.bib file:

```
@article{bilson1978rational,
title={Rational expectations and the exchange rate},
author={Bilson, John FO},
journal={The economics of exchange rates: Selected studies},
pages={75--96},
year={1978}
}
```

> But here is my result.....
>   [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have run `bibtex` after `pdflatex`?

Comment: I assume, that the `\cite` command and the real reference slide shouldn't be on the same frame?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, the document is called `foo.tex`

Running `pdflatex foo ; bibtex foo ; pdflatex foo; pdflatex foo` this will provide the correct citation. The important step is `bibtex` and recompile twice after `bibtexing`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{filecontents}{abc.bib}
@article{bilson1978rational,
title={Rational expectations and the exchange rate},
author={Bilson, John FO},
journal={The economics of exchange rates: Selected studies},
pages={75--96},
year={1978}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Reference}
\cite{bilson1978rational}.
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{abc.bib} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to run bibtex. I used to use 'biblatex' package in normal article...

Comment: @AlexShen: You could use `biblatex` in beamer as well